# List consult in JavaScript, which is the best

Tags: query

I have a list and I want to consult another list with JavaScript....
I am using this code: (  )

```
    function consultBP() {

    try
    {   
        var customlist ;
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle( 'WO_Projects' );   
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.set_viewXml( '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
           '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>' );

        this.customlist = oList.getItems( camlQuery );
        clientContext.load( this.customlist );
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(            
            Function.createDelegate( this, onQuerySucceededClarityID ),
            Function.createDelegate( this, onQueryFailedClarityID ));

    }catch(err){
        erroSearchBP++;
        if( erroSearchBP < 100 ) setTimeout( function() { consultBP(); } ,200 );
        else alert( erroCarregarPagina );
    }
    }

function onQuerySucceededClarityID(){
//........
}

function onQueryFailedClarityID( sender, args ) { 
    alert( "Failed" ); 
}
```

Is there a better way to consult another list in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are fetching items from the list is perfectly acceptable. As an alternative (not necessarily a better alternative, but more flexible), would be to use AJAX and SharePoint Web Services. One thing to note, is there isn't any way to call SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync in a loop and retrieve the results. For example, suppose you wanted to loop through all subwebs and look at a list called "Tasks". You can do this in AJAX.

AJAX example:

```
function getSubWebProjStatus() {
    $.each(subWebsArray, function() {
        var subSiteUrl = this.Url;
        var targetUrl = this.Url + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
        var listName = "Project Tasks";
        var soapEnv = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
            "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
            " <soap:Body> <GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\"> <listName>" + listName +
            "</listName> <viewName></viewName> <query></query> <viewFields></viewFields>" +
            " <rowLimit>2000</rowLimit> <queryOptions><QueryOptions xmlns=\"\">" +
            "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" +
            "<ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"/>" +
            "</QueryOptions></queryOptions>" +
            " </GetListItems> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: targetUrl,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems");
            },
            complete: function(msg) {
                var siteStatus = "N/A";
                var percentComplete = 0;
                if (msg.status === 200) {
                    var totalTaskCount = $(msg.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").length;
                    var completedTaskCount = 0;
                    if (totalTaskCount > 0) {
                        $(msg.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {
                            if ($(this).attr("ows_Status") !== undefined && $(this).attr("ows_Status").length > 0) {
                                var taskStatus = $(this).attr("ows_Status").split("#")[1];
                                if (taskStatus === "Completed") {
                                    completedTaskCount++;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        percentComplete = Math.round(completedTaskCount / totalTaskCount * 100);
                        siteStatus = completedTaskCount + " of " + totalTaskCount + " (" + percentComplete + "%) Tasks Completed";
                    }
                    displayProjStatus(subSiteUrl, siteStatus, percentComplete);
                } else {
                    //Failure
                    var errorCode = $(msg.responseXML).find("errorcode").text();
                    var errorString = $(msg.responseXML).find("errorstring").text();
                    if (errorString.length === 0) {
                        errorString = $(msg.responseXML).find("faultstring").text();
                    }
                    errorString = errorString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
                    showStatusBar("Oh no! " + errorString + "(" + errorCode + ")");
                }
            },
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i still cant vote for you, have no reputation :(

Comment: You owe me one ;-)